# How to create a form with two input fields where both require file uploads, using html and google apps script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to request users to upload files in two separate fields by adapting codes from here (https://www.bpwebs.com/upload-files-to-google-drive-with-google-apps-script/). It works only in the form with one file field. Can anyone point out my mistakes? It seems like uploadFiles() function can't take in two elements of type file? I tried but this is way beyond my capability. Thanks in advance!

code.gs

```
var folderID = "root"; 
    var sheetName = "Data"; 

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
    var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
        var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

        function intialSetup () {
          var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
        }

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
    
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);


    var fileUrl = "";
    var fileName = "";
    var fileUrl2 = "";
    var fileName2 = "";

    //Upload file if exists and update the file url
    if (formObject.myFile1.length > 0) {
      var blob = formObject.myFile1;
      var file = folder.createFile(blob);
      file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
      fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      fileName = file.getName();
    } else{
      fileUrl = "Record saved without a file";
    }
    
    //Upload file if exists and update the file url
    if (formObject.myFile2.length > 0) {
      var blob2 = formObject.myFile2;
      var file2 = folder.createFile(blob2);
      file2.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
      fileUrl2 = file2.getUrl();
      fileName2 = file2.getName();
    } else{
      fileUrl2 = "Record saved without a file";
    }

    //Saving records to Google Sheet
    sheet.appendRow([
      formObject.myName,
      formObject.myEmail,
      formObject.myNum,
      fileName,
      fileUrl,
      fileName2,
      fileUrl2,
      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
    
    return true;
    
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Uploads</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
          <h1>Personal Details</h1><hr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Please state your name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="myName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Please provide your email address.</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" name="myEmail"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Please provide your contact number (optional)</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="myNum"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       <br><br>
            <label>Upload photo/video</label>
                <input type="file" name="myFile1">
            <br>
            <label>Upload photo/video</label>
                <input type="file" name="myFile2">         
            <br>        
          <br>
          <button type="submit" onclick = submitForm(this.form)>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    function preventFormSubmit() {
          var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
          for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
            });
          }
        }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

    function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
      google.script.run.uploadFiles(formObject);
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could just use one and validate to make sure the number of files is two.

Comment: But I needed two input fields for two different files, and later I'll need to add in more fields for additional information on each of the two files too

Comment: You can upload different files with the same input field as a they're in the same folder just add multiple to the tag

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but for now I really need to separate the two input fields. Can you advise me on why the code doesn't work?

Comment: Where's it failing?

Comment: I don't see a javascript funtion named submitForm `<button type="submit" onclick = submitForm(this.form)>Submit</button>`

Comment: Why did you use createTemplateFromFile? I don't see any scriplets in the file

Comment: Instead of this `<button type="submit" onclick = submitForm(this.form)>Submit</button>`I would use `<input type="button" value="submit" />` and don't use the onclick even since you have onSubmit in the Form tag.

Comment: It can add data like name, email and number to the google sheet alright, but not the images if I asked for two. In the cell where the url supposes to be is 'Record saved without a file'. I tried changing the submit button as you suggested, but it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### HTML&Javascript side:

In this modification, please modify your HTML function as follows.

##### From:

```
<button type="submit" onclick = submitForm(this.form)>Submit</button>
```

##### To:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

In this modification, please modify your `uploadFiles` function as follows.

##### From:

```
var fileUrl = "";
var fileName = "";
var fileUrl2 = "";
var fileName2 = "";

//Upload file if exists and update the file url
if (formObject.myFile1.length > 0) {
  var blob = formObject.myFile1;
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);
  file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
  fileUrl = file.getUrl();
  fileName = file.getName();
} else{
  fileUrl = "Record saved without a file";
}

//Upload file if exists and update the file url
if (formObject.myFile2.length > 0) {
  var blob2 = formObject.myFile2;
  var file2 = folder.createFile(blob2);
  file2.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
  fileUrl2 = file2.getUrl();
  fileName2 = file2.getName();
} else{
  fileUrl2 = "Record saved without a file";
}

//Saving records to Google Sheet
sheet.appendRow([
  formObject.myName,
  formObject.myEmail,
  formObject.myNum,
  fileName,
  fileUrl,
  fileName2,
  fileUrl2,
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
```

##### To:

```
var files = ["myFile1", "myFile2"].flatMap(e => {
  var file = folder.createFile(formObject[e]);
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var fileUrl = "Record saved without a file";
  if (file.getSize() > 0 && fileName != "Untitled") {
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
    fileUrl = file.getUrl();
  } else {
    fileName = "";
    file.setTrashed(true);
  }
  return [fileName, fileUrl];
});
sheet.appendRow([
  formObject.myName,
  formObject.myEmail,
  formObject.myNum,
  ...files,
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
]);
```

#### Note:

- In December 2021, at V8 runtime, the form object including the file object got to be able to be correctly parsed from Javascript to Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/09/fixed-google-apps-script-web-app-html-form-file-input-fields-not-in-blob-compatible-format/) The bug has been resolved. It seems that about the file object, in the current stage, the object can be created as a file using `createFile` method. But, unfortunately, it seems that the file content cannot be directly retrieved from the form object. So, as a workaround, after the file was created as a file from the parsed form object, I used the method for checking the file size and the filename. If an error like `Forms with file inputs must be the only parameter.` doesn't occur, when 2nd argument can be used like `google.script.run.uploadFiles(formObject, arg2)`, the process can be simpler. But, in this situation, I used this workaround.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: It works! Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do